# adding rows inside grid extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to add rows dynamically inside a grid using a button and remove individual rows using an action column function.  I have two text fields (name, email) inside the grid on each row. So when the user hits the add button, a new row should appear with name and email fields. The third column would be an action column and when the button in the action column is clicked the entire row should be removed.

It would greatly help me out if somebody could share some sample code for me to get started.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great code examples [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/). This is where you have to head first, before asking here.

Look at this [row editing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/row-editing.html) example.